# Cinnamon desktop- software rending mode issue

Tags: cinnamon

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with the cinnamon desktop. An update or something installed and asked me to restart the computer. I did, and it booted into software rendering mode. I can't move the mouse, and the keyboard seems to have no effect. Its a multi-user computer. How to I get it out of software rendering mode. Please help!! Thank you so much in advance!!

[EDIT]
I booted up a livecd, and read my bash-log. The last command I put in before the accident was:


`sudo apt-get install milutils
sudo dpkg --configure -a`

I was prompted to restart the computer, and boom! it was about as usable as a brick.
Thanks in advance, and please help!!

Comment: You seem to have run into an incompatibility issue.  What is the output of `lsb_release --codename`?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I found is:

If you have `software-properties-common` installed in a mint 17.1 Rebecca or Ubuntu 14.01 - 14.01.1 cinnamon system, use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon*
```

To get rid of it and get your other cinnamon stuffs back. That fixes mine. Not sure about Mate or others.

Comment: Is there a way to do this from a livecd?

Comment: Never mind, I am just going to do a reinstall